# What is the problem in this script when I want to upload an image?

Tags: node.js, express

What is the problem in this script? When I want to upload an image I found this problem:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\MERN_Stack_Project_WeConnect_Social_Media-master\server\public\uploads\profile_pic\1611529212065_0.jfif'
```

```
changeProfilePic(req, res) {
    let profile_pic = req.file.filename
    let loggedInUser = req.userDetails._id
    let reqUserId = req.body.id
    let oldPic = req.body.oldPic

    if (oldPic !== "user.png") {
        const filePath = `../server/public/uploads/profile_pic/${oldPic}`;
        fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            if (reqUserId === loggedInUser) {
                userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(loggedInUser, {
                    profile_pic
                }).exec((err, result) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) }
                    res.json({ result })
                })
            } else {
                res.status(404)
            }
        })
    } else {
        if (reqUserId === loggedInUser) {
            userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(loggedInUser, {
                profile_pic
            }).exec((err, result) => {
                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                res.json({ result })
            })
        } else {
            res.status(404)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1611529212065_0.jfif` doesn't exist at that path

Comment: so what i will add it

Comment: It's possible you're reaching a limit on the length of file pathnames. Use shorter names for your folders, and don't nest your development stuff so deeply in subdirectories.